# Simple pagination and how to create the links

Tags: html, css, algorithm

I am trying to implement pagination. I am trying to figure out the algorithm to create the navigation links.
Example:

```
<ul id="mystyle">  
<li class="previous">«Previous</li>  
<li class="active">1</li>  
<li><a href="?page=2">2</a></li>  
<li><a href="?page=3">3</a></li>  
<li><a href="?page=4">4</a></li>  
<li><a href="?page=5">5</a></li>  
<li><a href="?page=6">6</a></li>  
<li><a href="?page=7">7</a></li>  
<li class="next"><a href="?page=2">Next »</a></li>  
</ul>
```

So this creates 7 links for the result set. My problem is, what happens if the result set is too small and only requires e.g. 2 links.
Is there some example of how to take this into account?

Comment: What dynamic language are you using?

Comment: @JoshC:JSP but basic staff. I assume that this is language agnostic? Would be the same in sevlets,php etc?

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to generate the number of pages according to your dynamic language.
For example in php you could generate one line per entry in a table using the index of the table as the page.

Comment: My question is about the links that are customarily shown at the bottom of the page: `Previous<1,2,3,4,5,6,7>Next` Where each link is a href to the corresponding page

Comment: Yes but you need to develop this system yourself, either in javascript or php. For an example you could check this link:
http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/making-a-jquery-pagination-system/

Comment: The idea is that you have the number of pages available in your php or javascript code, and you generate the page selector using that... It's a bit long to explain in a comment though :) If you look for google - javascript pagination you will find an example easily (if the one above doesn't work for you)